# Changing resolution for samsung monitor?

Tags: monitor, samsung, display-resolution

I am using ubuntu from a usb for the first time and i cant seem to change the resolution to full hd ( 1920 x 1080 ) on my samsung monitor, the max res is 1280 x 1024 and my monitor is `unknown` and my refresh rate is 0 Hz.
Thank you

Comment: Please post the output of `sudo lspci` by editing you question.

Answer (score 0):

This is such a common problem... * sigh *

The easiest thing to do is add that resolution using `xrandr` - a quick google search will bring up plenty of guides. You would then need to add the `xrandr` configurations to a startup file, so that you'll get your desired resolution upon reboot/startup.

You can do all this hassle-free using a simple program; [ResolutionX](http://www.sourceforge.com/p/resolutionx) - it is a graphical front-end to `randr`, so if `xrandr` works for you, so will that.